# Synchronize mod status with chatroom ownership

Tags: bug, chat, moderators, moderator-abilities, room-owner

As far as I can tell, changes in mod status -- becoming a mod, or ceasing to be -- does not immediately affect which rooms that user owns.

When a site enters beta and gets a chatroom, the pro-tem mods are installed as owners of the site room, and the mod-only room of that site.

However, later changes in the mod team are not reflected in the list of owners, meaning that ex-mods retain access (unless any of the other owners/mods remember to take action), and new mods may not have full control (I'm not sure if they are chat-almighty by being mods, anyway).

I think that room ownership of site rooms should be synced with the moderator list automatically.

Comment: This may be a feature if some sites want non-mods to be chat owners. I can not imagine this being the case for the mod-only room, though.

Answer (score 7):

New moderators are not automatically made room owner, that all happens manually. They still have access to private rooms on their site, but that is a direct consequence of the diamond. Room ownership is pretty useless for moderators, it doesn't change any of their abilities in chat.

Private chat rooms should generally not add any room owners. Usually the only owner is the moderator that first created the room.

It probably makes sense to remove any access to private rooms if a moderator loses their diamond. It is just an easy thing to overlook. But I don't see any need for any true synchronization.

Comment: Assume the mod team changes completely. Removing access for the old one but not adding it for the new one means no one has access to the mod-only room.

Comment: Related: [Prevent non-moderators from owning private rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216466/335251) – per the answer by Oded (who was a staff member at the time) from August 2016: "A daily job goes through private rooms and removes anyone who is not a moderator from the list of room owners."